# Missing/Lost file out put when using multiprocessing with python and pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a set of stocks price history, contains 8160 files under folder 'Raw'. I than using pandas to do some adjustments on each of them, than output a new file into another folder 'Cleaned'. Any file failed to process, should be write into a folder called 'Failed'.

All files are csv.

After I run the code below, I found that there are no files under failed. But around 100 files are missing. 'Clean' folder only contains 8060 files.

I checked the difference and find out what are the missing files. I found that all files are in correct format and could be processed normally if I do it the for loop way. So I suspect that maybe I didn't use the multiprocess correctly.

Here are the codes.

```
def cleanup(file):
    print('Working on ' + file)
    stock = pd.read_csv(raw_folder_path + file)

    try:
        del stock['Unnamed: 0']
        stock['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(stock['datetime'],unit='ms',utc=True).dt.tz_convert('America/New_York').dt.date
        stock.to_csv(clean_folder_path + file)
    except:
        print(file + ' Not Successfull')
        stock.to_csv(failed_folder_path + file)

#run multiprocessing
files_list = os.listdir(raw_folder_path)
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
pool.map(cleanup, files_list)
```

I hope someone could guild me where I did wrong with this? Thank you!

Comment: If `stock.to_csv` fails it may not write neither to clean nor to failed folders.

Comment: BTW, main process should run all its code in `if __name__ == '__main__':` block. Is it the case for you? Because child processes are all running same script as main, except for that childs have `__name__` different from `__main__`.

Comment: Also you may try to emulate intentional exception in one of child processes and try to see if main process catches and reports that exception. It might be the case that main process didn't catch some error of child. This could explain that writing csv was ignored in both folders silently. If main doesn't report exceptions when using `map()` then you should use [Manager Proxy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#proxy-objects) to exchange exception and other info between child and main process.

Comment: Also correct way of using a pool is within `with` operator like this `with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:   pool.map(cleanup, files_list)`. Otherwise pool is not closed and processes are not terminated in some cases. Also errors may be left unseen.

Comment: Also after both of `to_csv(...)` strings you may add assertion `assert os.path.exists(csv_path)` so that you're sure that csv file got created and not skipped errors silently. Then `assert` for sure will create exception which will be catched by main in case if `.map()` really reports all exceptions.

Comment: And the last main recommendation is that your child-processing function should always return result, e.g. return `True` when all is OK, return `False` if there were errors. Then collect results in main, i.e. instead of `pool.map(cleanup, files_list)` do this `results = pool.map(cleanup, files_list)` and check results next line as `assert all(results)`. This will definitely ensure that map didn't skip any error, because all errors will be reported by child functions through `True/False`.

Comment: @Arty wow you are awesome. Thanks for these good advises. I will try them and back to you later. This is very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: I've created an answer with all these recommended code fixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put recommendations into comments of question. The final code should probably look like this:

[Try it online here!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64051993#main.py)

```
import multiprocessing, os, datetime
import pandas as pd

raw_folder_path = './input/'
clean_folder_path = './clean/'
failed_folder_path = './failed/'

def cleanup(file):
    print('Working on ' + file)
    stock = pd.read_csv(raw_folder_path + file)

    try:
        del stock['Unnamed: 0']
        stock['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(stock['datetime'],unit='ms',utc=True).dt.tz_convert('America/New_York').dt.date
        stock.to_csv(clean_folder_path + file)
        assert os.path.exists(clean_folder_path + file)
        return True
    except Exception as ex:
        print(file + ' Not Successfull ', ex)
        stock.to_csv(failed_folder_path + file)
        assert os.path.exists(failed_folder_path + file)
        return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    files_list = os.listdir(raw_folder_path)
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        results = pool.map(cleanup, files_list)
    assert all(results), f'{len(results) - sum(results)} wrong results!'
    assert len(results) == len(files_list)
```

Comment: Thank you @Arty. Your code is clean and beautiful. Very helpful to me. Thanks for providing this high quality answer!